# R programming: Replace string in data frame if string in list

Tags: r

I need to group clients in a sales data base. Example database:

```
         CLIENT.CODE    PRODUCT    SALES              
          AA1            B          5
          AA3            B          5
          BB4            B          5
          AC87           B          5
```

I need to do 2 things:

1# Create a list:
list (AA1 , AC87)

2# Change my data frame so that if the client code is in that list I will modify to another code

Result:

```
         CLIENT.CODE    PRODUCT    SALES              
          Groupe         B          5
          AA3            B          5
          BB4            B          5
          Groupe         B          5
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse`

```
df
#  CLIENT.CODE PRODUCT SALES
#1         AA1       B     5
#2         AA3       B     5
#3         BB4       B     5
#4        AC87       B     5

client_codes <- c("AA1", "AC87")
df$CLIENT.CODE <- ifelse(df$CLIENT.CODE %in% client_codes, 
                         "Groupe", as.character(df$CLIENT.CODE))

df
#  CLIENT.CODE PRODUCT SALES
#1      Groupe       B     5
#2         AA3       B     5
#3         BB4       B     5
#4      Groupe       B     5
```

Comment: the code works but I do not want to have numeric values for client.codes in the output dataset. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Sorry wasn't paying attention. Updated to use character rather than factors.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `gsub` and forget about the list?  This way you can capture the result in one line without having to create `client_code`.

```
> dat
##  CLIENT.CODE PRODUCT SALES
##1         AA1       B     5
##2         AA3       B     5
##3         BB4       B     5
##4        AC87       B     5
> dat$CLIENT.CODE <- gsub("(AA1)|(AC87)", "Groupe", dat$CLIENT.CODE)
> dat
##  CLIENT.CODE PRODUCT SALES
##1      Groupe       B     5
##2         AA3       B     5
##3         BB4       B     5
##4      Groupe       B     5
```